# In VHDL, how to check a case statement value partially meets some signal values and the rest don't matter?

Tags: vhdl

```
case (my_state_val & val_q) is
    when ("000" & "00") => do something;
    when ("001" & "00") => do something else;
    when ("010" & "10") => do a 3rd thing;
    when ("100" & "DONT CARE") => do a non-default thing because my_state_val is valid;
    when others => default state or null;
end case;
```

If it was an if check, I could do: `val_q /= "11"` because I know my counter will never reach the top value. How can I do this in a case statement?

The reason why I want a case statement is because I don't want a 30+ depth branches.

```
if 1 then
elsif 2 then
...
elsif 25 then
elsif 26 then
elsif 27 then
else
end if;
```

Comment: Without declarations provided for `my_state_val` or `val_q` your case expression (`(my_state_val & val_q)` replete with redundant parentheses) is only legal in -2008 which also provides a *matching case statement*  with specific syntax (IEEE Std 1076-2008  10.9 Case statement) which allows the use of a of the  '-' character representing a std_ulogic value in a choice. Likely not supported for synthesis (other than Vivado). If you're case expression were of a scalar type you could provide choices that were a range of values.

Comment: I simulated with '-' (in 2008 VHDL) but have not yet attempted to synthesis. Also my signals are std_logic_vector(# downto 0).

Comment: I have had a similar problem, in the end, I wrote a very large if statement as I realised I could get away with it. Your problem, however, seems to already have implied preferential treatment for the `my_state_val` signal, maybe you can create a case statement for that particular signal, then break down each of the sub-cases into if statements or case statements.

Comment: Another alternative would be to create constants of type `type'(my_state_val & val_q)` (VHDL 2008) and then you could put it in one big case statement?

Comment: hey dyslexicgrufallo, I didn't want a long if elsif priority encoder. I assume its an issue with timing if its long enough. I did however use an if statement to check my_state_val first equals "100" else it goes into case statement. so I removed `when ("100" & "--") =>` because user1155120 scared me about the not synthesize-able remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest either this:

`case (my_state_val & val_q) is
        when ("000" & "00") => do something;
        when ("001" & "00") => do something else;
        when ("010" & "10") => do a 3rd thing;
        when others =>
            if my_state_val == "100" then 
                do a non-default thing because my_state_val is valid
            else
                default state or null;
            end if;
        end case;`

Or this:

`case (my_state_val) is
        when ("000") => Evaluate val_q;
        when ("001") => Evaluate val_q;
        when ("010") => Evaluate val_q;
        when ("100") => Evaluate val_q;
        when others  => default state or null;
    end case;`

Comment: I used a similar approach to your first answer, but I'll use your version if something errors out during synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I initially attempted this:

```
case (my_state_val & val_q) is
    when ... => ....;
    ...
    when ("100" & "--") => do something;
    when others => null;
end case;
```

Simulation worked. However, my mentors are used to non-2008 VHDL and even if it was synthesize-able, it could raise questions by other engineers. So I want something that passes our coding guidelines.

I used an if-else wrapped around this case statement.

```
 if my_state_val = "100" then
     my do something here;
 else
     case (my_state_val & val_q) is
        when ... => ....;
        ...
        -- removed "--"
        when others => null;
    end case;
end if;
```